# HTML table with different count of td

Tags: html, html-table

For logo and and menu I have table with two rows. And Picture of person. Upper part of the body is on first row and lower part is on second row. First row should have only one `td` that is logo of the site and in second row i should make multiple `td` Can someone help me with that task. I should use tables because my client want it.

Comment: 1. I would try to convince the client to not use tables for this.  (easier said than done, I am sure)  2.  Pls provide the code of what you have already done and maybe a link to some example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `colspan` attribute on a `<td>` element to make it fit more than one column, just increase the number to however many columns you want it to fit across

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Long column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Small</td>
        <td>Column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

jou can use `collspan` (like in cell[2,0]), further info: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/td/colspan

[image: collspanrowspan]